# How can I detect when an element scrolls into the viewport

Tags: javascript

I have a banner ad at the bottom of my site. I'm using Google Analytics events to keep track of impressions. The problem is that if the user doesn't scroll to the bottom, they won't see the banner. So recording an impression will cause inaccuracies unless I can wait until the banner is in the viewport.

How would I detect that my banner ad (with an `id` of `#footer-banner`) has entered the viewport? I'd prefer if it only got detected once the entire height of the banner was visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can:

```
function isInView() {
  var y = $('foot-banner').position().top;
  var windowY = $(window).scrollTop();
  return y > windowY && y < windowY + $(window).height();
}
```

Then this function can be used when a scroll event is triggered:

```
var impressionRecorded = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if (isInView() && !impressionRecorded) {
     impressionRecorded = true;
     // record impression
  }
});
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong in this, but as this is a function, wouldn't I have to call it at some point for it to work? How exactly would I implement this into my site?

Comment: added a way to use this function

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin for this:
https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy

permit to detect enter and exit in viewport.