# Detect element currently in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a fixed header, and I am trying to get the `li` elements within the nav to change styling based on the user's window based on current scroll point.

I'm under the impression that the best way to do this would be if I worked out what element was currently at the top of the viewport. If I've got 4+ `divs` all with the class `page-section`, how do I find the `id` of the one currently at the top of the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect when an element scrolls into the viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865815/how-can-i-detect-when-an-element-scrolls-into-the-viewport)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rediscovered this question of mine.

I was looking for the [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) js library.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,

You can try with [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method. It will give you the element position respect to the viewport. Look at the logic of the next code, it will give you a clue to achieve your work (The important part is the first code of `checkVisibleSection` function):

**HTML Code**

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li data-section="1"><a class="active" href="#">Section 1</a></li>
  <li data-section="2"><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
  <li data-section="3"><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
  <li data-section="4"><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
  <li data-section="5"><a href="#">Section 5</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="section1" class="section" data-section="1">
  <header>Section 1</header>
</section>

<section id="section2" class="section" data-section="2">
  <header>Section 2</header>
</section>

<section id="section3" class="section" data-section="3">
  <header>Section 3</header>
</section>

<section id="section4" class="section" data-section="4">
  <header>Section 4</header>
</section>

<section id="section5" class="section" data-section="5">
  <header>Section 5</header>
</section>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var nav         = document.getElementById("navigation"),
    sections    = document.querySelectorAll(".section"),
    delay       = null;

//---Scroll logic
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

    if(!isNaN(delay)){ clearTimeout(delay); }

    delay = setTimeout(checkVisibleSection, 100);

});

//---Check the visible section
function checkVisibleSection(){

    var minor   = window.innerHeight,
        section = null;

    //---Select the section closest to the top
    [].forEach.call(sections, function(item){

        var offset  = item.getBoundingClientRect();

        if(Math.abs(offset.top) < minor){

            minor   = Math.abs(offset.top);

            section = item;

        }

    });

    //---If the section exists
    if(section){

        var index   = section.dataset.section,
            link    = nav.querySelector("li[data-section='" + index + "'] a");

        //---If the link is not already active
        if(!link.classList.contains("active")){

            //---Remove the active class
            nav.querySelector("a.active").classList.remove("active");

            //---Add the active class
            link.classList.add("active");

        }

    }

}

//---Click on buttons
nav.addEventListener("click", function(evt){

    evt.preventDefault();

    var link = evt.target;

    if(link.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "a"){

        var section = link.parentNode.dataset.section;

        //---Remove the class of the active link
        nav.querySelector("a.active").classList.remove("active");

        //---Active the link
        link.classList.add("active");

        //---Scroll to the section
        document.getElementById("section" + section).scrollIntoView();

        document.body.scrollTop -= 30;

    }

});
```

Here you have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/542pg1xn/) with a working example.